# internet explorer cannot open the internet site

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, updatepanel, servercontrols

I have weird error, but that only appears to be happening in IE6, and it happens randomly.
I’m implementing omniture analytics on my company’s site. I made a literal server control and called it from inside an update panel. All the control does is build the java script and uses ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Control, Type, String, String, Boolean) to add the java script to the page. This all works great except for the random bug (see attached picture).

From what I’ve read, it appears to be a bug in IE6 that renders the java script wrong if its created in a child element inside the body tag, which my script ends up inside a form tag. I’m just wondering if there is any other method I can use to register the control that won’t cause this error.

[Image http://img132.imageshack.us/my.php?image=errornf7.jpg](http://img132.imageshack.us/my.php?image=errornf7.jpg)

// I cant seem to get the image to show up correctly, so I'll just link to it.

[Error Screenshot](http://img132.imageshack.us/my.php?image=errornf7.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if this ends up being completely off-base, but I remember running into something like this a while back.  I fixed it by adding 'defer' to my script tag, i.e.:

```
<script defer="true"> ... </script>
```

This prevents the script from running until the rest of the page has finished loading, which avoids an IE DOM bug that sounds very similar to what you're getting.  I haven't used ASP, though, so I don't know how you would add the defer attribute through ScriptManager.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I actually read that solution before I posted here, and tried it. However, the script never got rendered to the page when I added it. I'm guessing it doesn't work with ScriptManager/updatepanel.

Comment: It Works (TM)! Had the same problem (a jQUery plugin was trying to run before DOM was ready).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a case of the script modifying the DOM before it has loaded. If I were you I would look at adding the script when the DOM is ready. Plenty of JS libraries have ways of doing this.

More information on this sort of error: http://blog.mjjames.co.uk/2007/11/knowing-whats-on-your-page.html

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem as well. I found it affects IE6 and some versions of IE7 as well. In my case the problem was actually being caused by the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method. Once I removed that it worked fine